# Powerpoint global button

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I think it's a simple question for anybody with some VBA skills oder PowerPoint-pro's:

I have a presentation like a quiz, and I like to offer three jokers like in WWTBAM.
So I created three buttons and i made the 50:50 button, that on click an animation starts so, that to wrong answers are hidden. So I now just want to, that if you clicked the joker-button on one slide, it have to be removed / disabled / crossed on ALL other following slides.

Is there anybody who can show me a simple snippet which will do that?

That would be really great.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you going in the right direction:

```
Option Explicit

' The name of the shape(s) to search for
' (name shapes in the Selection Pane : Alt+F10 for PowerPoint 2010 and later)
Public Const ShapeName = "50/50"

' Purpose:  Macro to HIDE all shapes on all slides that match the specified name
' Usage:    Assign to any shape(s) on a slide via the Insert Tab / Action / Mouse Click / Run Macro
' Author:   Jamie Garroch of YOUpresent Ltd. (http://youpresent.co.uk/)
Public Sub HideAll()
  Dim oSld As Slide
  Dim oShp As Shape
  For Each oSld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each oShp In oSld.Shapes
      If oShp.Name = ShapeName Then oShp.Visible = msoFalse
    Next
  Next
End Sub

' Purpose:  Macro to SHOW all shapes on all slides that match the specified name
' Usage:    Assign to any shape(s) on a slide via the Insert Tab / Action / Mouse Click / Run Macro
' Author:   Jamie Garroch of YOUpresent Ltd. (http://youpresent.co.uk/)
Public Sub ShowAll()
  Dim oSld As Slide
  Dim oShp As Shape
  For Each oSld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each oShp In oSld.Shapes
      If oShp.Name = ShapeName Then oShp.Visible = msoTrue
    Next
  Next
End Sub
```